# Resizing every view to fit again after toggling setStatusBarHidden:YES to setStatusBarHidden:NO

Tags: ios, user-interface, overlay

I have a UIView that I want to add to the keyWindow so that it covers everything (including the StatusBar). When I add the view I remove the statusBar using the following piece of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:aView];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
aView.frame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow bounds];
```

Everything looks as expected. If I then remove the view and add the statusbar again, everything is fine. However, things go wrong when I rotate my device and then remove the view. The UI is now partially covered by the statusBar (in this case a nav bar). Rotating the device immediately resizes everything so that the UI looks normal again.

How can I ensure the UI (any UI!) is aware of the StatusBar unhiding again so that it  adjusts automatically as soon as the UIView is removed from the keyWindow.?

The solution should work, regardless of the type of UI in the App. I happen to use a tab bar and a navigation controller in this particular example, but that doesn't always have to be the case.

Comment: Anyone have a clue? I'm sure I'm not alone with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have just solved this problem.

In my situation, it is caused by the order you call the method.And sometimes maybe the animation also have something to do with this.

for example,in my situation:

//call present view controller after call setStatusBarHidden

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[modalPresentedViewController presentModalViewController:self animated:YES];
```

//call setStatusBarHidden before call the dismiss method.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[modalPresentedViewController presentModalViewController:self animated:YES];
```

I hope this will help.